# Append to Kafka log iff the current timestamp is T?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, optimistic-concurrency

I want to use Apache Kafka for an event-sourcing-like scenario. I am looking for a way to mimic optimistic concurrency when writing to a log stream. I.e., if I try to write a new log entry which has been created based on the knowledge of a previous timestamp T, I want to get an exception if someone else, concurrently, updated the stream (to a timestamp T') before I get to write my event.

Is there a way to achieve optimistic concurrency with Apache Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should try to sort this out in the producer, sort it out in the consumer. I assume T'>T (i.e. T' is later than T), but `message(T')` is written before `message(T)`. You should do the following

1. Make sure both messages end up in the same partition, either by giving them the same key or by doing your own routing or by using just one partition.
2. Have the time stamp as part of the message.
3. Drop messages in the consumer which would go back in time.

When `message(T)` arrives in the consumer, it would go back in time, because `message(T')` was processed already and T<T', so `message(T)` is dropped as required.

Comment: That's too late, I don't want to write the entry to the log stream in the first place. The log stream should be my single source of truth of "events that happened". In case of concurrency problems, I want to fail at the producer and show a message to the user.

Comment: Ok, if you feel like my answer might deter others from answering your question, shall I delete it? I would be interested to know if there is a Kafka solution to this too, because currently I cannot imagine how the Kafka producer might help, because the producer is a rather simple, straight forward bit of code